# How do I run in Wine a program installed from an msi?

Tags: installation, unity, wine, msi

I have installed a .msi file with wine, by right-clicking on it and selecting "run with Wine". Wine has apparently succesfully installed the application: now how am I supposed to run it?

I have typed the name of the program in Ubuntu's launcher, and an item appears with that name and wine's icon, so I've tried to run that, but I get two popups one after the other with the following error messages:
- invalid parameter
- there is no window program configured to run this file

The program is called "inSSIDer" and I downloaded it from: http://files.metageek.net/downloads/inSSIDer-Installer-2.1.5.1393.msi

UPDATE:

```
$ wine start "c:\Program Files\MetaGeek\inSSIDer\inSSIDer.exe"
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
teo@XXX:~$ fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"configSections" in state 1
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"sectionGroup" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"section" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"section" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"userSettings" in state 1
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"inSSIDer.Properties.Settings" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"MetaScanner.Properties.Settings" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"setting" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"value" in state 3
wine: Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 applications.
```

Comment: Any reason why not to use iwScanner or kismet?

Comment: Note that inSSIDer will probably not work on Wine, since it needs direct access to the hardware / WiFi info, and Wine cannot provide that.

Answer (score 2):

Command line would be (adjust the directory if you installed it elsewhere):

```
wine start "c:/Program Files/MetaGeek/inSSIDer/bin/Inssider.exe"
```

And it will throw errors if something is wrong.

- You probably need `gdiplus` ....

  ```
  sh winetricks gdiplus
  ```
- You need to have `winetricks` installed for installing `gdiplus`.

  ```
  wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
  chmod +x winetricks
  ```

---

Regarding the current error:

```
wine: Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 applications.
```

So...

```
 winetricks mono21
```

Comment: Updated with the result of wine start "c:/Program Files/MetaGeek/inSSIDer/bin/Inssider.exe"

Comment: winetricks dotnet20 should also work (and in more cases), instead of mono21